# How to make react native flatlist auto scroll like a Marquee?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatlist.

```
<FlatList
            horizontal
            data={data}
            key={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            ListHeaderComponent={listHeader}
            renderItem={ // rendering some component }
/>
```

I want to make this flat list auto-scroll like a marquee text. I mean it should scroll slowly automatically till it reaches to end and again it should start from the beginning like a carousel.

Comment: `FlatList` is not what you need here. Try to animate it manually using the `Animated` API.

Comment: I used react-native-auto-scrolling for this. And it is working super fine.

Comment: Good for you. Actually, this library uses `Animated` internally. Also, I suggest you check: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/10278150

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-native-marquee.
Check for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-marquee

And just add your flatlist between marquee tags:

```
<Marquee
 speed={1}
 marqueeOnStart={true}
 loop={true}>
 <FlatList
   horizontal
   data={data}
   key={(item, index) => index.toString()}
   ListHeaderComponent={listHeader}
   renderItem={ // rendering some component }
 />
<Marquee/>
```